# Replicating Google Search Grey Search Suggestions

Tags: search, autosuggest

I have a search feature that does auto suggest when you type. But I'm really looking for that shadow text feature that Google has. Anyone know how to go about putting that feature together? Point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your questions correctly but I think you are talking about the the first auto-suggest result which is pushed in grey. Just use your suggestion's first result as that "Shadow Text".